# Is there a way to write a batch of records, expecting some to fail?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Say there is a system outage; record of 1 page visit for every 100 did not make it to your Spanner instance for some reason. Probably QA's fault. Anyway, you have a different store of data from which you can upload to Spanner. Great! Assuming you have a significant number of records, you'll batch them together, maybe sending up 1000 at a time. But 990 of those 1000 are likely to already exist in spanner, so your insert operation will fail. You could upload one-by-one, but you take a huge perf hit for that. You could even try some adaptive batch size, but that winds up getting a bit more complicated.

Is there an easy way to solve this? I want `dbClient.writeAtLeastOnceIgnoreErrors(Iterable<Mutation>)`, but I don't think anything of that sort is available. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to send 1,000 mutations (inserts) to Spanner, knowing that many of those 1,000 records will already exist in Spanner. The easiest way to do that is to use an InsertOrUpdate mutation like this:

```java
Mutation m = Mutation.newInsertOrUpdateBuilder("YOUR_TABLE").set("COL1").to("some_val").build();
dbClient.writeAtLeastOnce(m);
```

InsertOrUpdate will do exactly what you would expect, i.e. only insert records that do not already exist, and update the records that do already exist without returning any errors. You must supply a value for all NOT NULL columns in your table.

Comment: FYI, this works for existing rows, but if the error is parent not found for linked tables, it seems something more manual is needed

Comment: Am I right to assume that the table you are using is interleaved in a parent table (your question doesn't mention this)? If that is the case, you need to do an `InsertOrUpdate` for the parent table before you do the `InsertOrUpdate` for the child table. It is not possible to insert a child record without the parent record, and it is also not possible to insert both the child- and parent record in one mutation.

Comment: Yes that's correct - the issue is more I want a batch of updates to go through, and some to fail quietly. As it is now, I either need to load all the parents and manually check the values on my side, or catch exceptions and retry with different batches.